# Parsing complex nest of NSDictionaries and Arrays to a simpler NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm in a bit over my head here (a lot actually). I have a JSON response that's been converted to an NSDictionary. It's a mess of nested arrays and dictionaries within dictionaries within arrays, etc... I have no clue what to do with it. What I would like to do is make a simple NSDictionary for each "item" and use the properties to drive a UITableView. I don't know how to access objects several levels down. I've done a bit of searching and i see there's several ways to go about it (fast enumeration, blocks, etc..) but before I start spinning my wheels I'd love to know what would be best for my particular situation. I saved the NSDictionary as a plist for readability. I'll post it here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>search_result</key>
    <dict>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <string>51.508129</string>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <string>-0.128005</string>
        <key>page</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>per_page</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>results</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>result</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>description_short</key>
                    <string>Experience the history and mystery of the most famous sites in the South of England!</string>
                    <key>flex_reference</key>
                    <string>FLX-LON-77B-D2F-5ED5</string>
                    <key>geocoded_latitude</key>
                    <string>51.5081289</string>
                    <key>geocoded_longitude</key>
                    <string>-0.128005</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Stonehenge, Glastonbury, Avebury and Chalice Well</string>
                    <key>primary_image</key>
                    <string>http://media.****.com/FLX-LON-77B-D2F-5ED5-image_original-56.jpg</string>
                    <key>product_categories</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>type</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Sightseeing Tours</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>category</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Excursion</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>type</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Attractions</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>result</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>description_short</key>
                    <string>Experience some of the most famous landmarks in English history, University City of Oxford, rolling countryside and honey stoned cottages of the Cotswolds and Stratford upon Avon home of the famous English plyright, William Shakespeare.</string>
                    <key>flex_reference</key>
                    <string>FLX-LON-2AD-267-38AB</string>
                    <key>geocoded_latitude</key>
                    <string>51.5081289</string>
                    <key>geocoded_longitude</key>
                    <string>-0.128005</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Oxford, Stratford and the Cotswolds Villages</string>
                    <key>primary_image</key>
                    <string>http://media.*****.com/FLX-LON-2AD-267-38AB-image_original-AF.jpg</string>
                    <key>product_categories</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>type</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Sightseeing Tours</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>category</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Excursion</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>type</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Attractions</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>result</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>description_short</key>
                    <string>The must see attractions of the United Kingdom, World Heritage sites, Stonehenge and the Roman Baths.</string>
                    <key>flex_reference</key>
                    <string>FLX-LON-65D-AC0-B08E</string>
                    <key>geocoded_latitude</key>
                    <string>51.5081289</string>
                    <key>geocoded_longitude</key>
                    <string>-0.128005</string>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>Stonehenge and Bath</string>
                    <key>primary_image</key>
                    <string>http://media.****.com/FLX-LON-65D-AC0-B08E-image_original-2E.jpg</string>
                    <key>product_categories</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>type</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Sightseeing Tours</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                        <dict>
                            <key>product_category</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>category</string>
                                <key>name</key>
                                <string>Excursion</string>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>total_pages</key>
        <integer>18</integer>
        <key>total_results</key>
        <integer>54</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What would you expect this to parse down to?

Comment: Which values should you put on the table view?

Comment: I want to use the "name" and "primary_image" for the tableview (possibly more in the future, but this is enough for now) and also use the "flex_referecnce" key for drilling down to a detail view.

Comment: Actually, an NSLog of the dictionary would be far more readable.  But a JSON string is a collection of nested "arrays" and "objects" (dictionaries).  You just peel the onion to get to what you want.  You can use `isKindOfClass` to find out whether you have an array or dictionary at any level, if it's at all dynamic.  For JSON that never varies in structure you can just look at the NSLog dump to figure it out.

Comment: I did do an NSLog of the dictionary to the console but it was tremendous and found this to be a lot easier to read. I actually renamed the above XML to a .plist and read it that way in XCode. From what I understand this JSON from this server is always the same format.

Comment: Well, the rest of us can read the NSLog (`dictionary.description`) much more easily, and it's far fewer characters/noise than the XML presentation.  Plus you need to become familiar with it, as it's very close to JSON in presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = /* get your dictionary from wherever */
NSDictionary *searchResults = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"search_result"];
NSArray *allResults = [searchResults objectForKey:@"results"];

for (NSDictionary *result in allResults)
{
    NSDictionary *resultDetails = [result objectForKey:@"result"];

    NSString *name = [resultDetails objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[resultDetails objectForKey:@"primary_image"]];

    NSLog(@"Name: %@\n URL: %@", name, imageURL);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I had to change "foreach" to "for" since xcode was throwing me a C99 error, and "image_name" to "primary_image" but it works brilliantly. Thanks a lot that was really elegant.

Comment: @JosephToronto: Oops, I keep forgetting that Objective-C doesn't use `foreach`. I think I was fiddling around in C# at the time I wrote this.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dict= jsonDict[@"search_results"];
```

The value for key "results" is an array:

```
NSArray* results = dict[@"results"];
```

At the first index there is a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dict2= results[0];
```

For the key "result" there is another dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dict3= dict2[@"result"];
```

From this dictionary you can retrieve the values that you want:

```
NSString* name= dict3[@"name"];
NSString* primaryImage= dict3[@"primary_image"];
```

No matter how many dicts and arrays you have, you can read one then you can read them all.To do this easier just think like they' re packets inside packets, and draw a graph with the objects.

**EDIT**

I didn't specify what dict was, added it.

Comment: That looks easier than I thought. I'll give it a try, thanks.